# SQL counting elements from two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to come up with a query that will allow me to count the values of two columns of the same table. For example

```
table: rider_geo_addresses
==================================
|id  | origin_id | destination_id |
==================================
 1        4             8
 1        2             6
 1        8             4
 1        6             2
 1        1             5
 1        2             8
```

i want a query that will give me the count of origin_id and destination_id combined sorted desc

```
table: result
============================
| geo_addresses  | counter |
============================
       8              3
       2              3
       6              2
       4              2
       5              1
       1              1
```

i tried to get the values on two separate tables and use **union** to combined them but it doesnt take into account the same values that may appear at both columns.
This is what i tried

```
select ( origin_id) as geo_addresses, count(origin_id) as counter
from rider_geo_addresses
where rider_profile_id
group by  origin_id
union
select ( destination_id) as geo_addresses, count(destination_id) as counter
from rider_geo_addresses
where rider_profile_id
group by  destination_id
order by counter desc;
```

Comment: *This is what i tried* Use this query as subquery, group and sum in outer query. But use UNION ALL, not UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: Can you explain why the result for geo_addresses  6 and 4 is 1?

Comment: @forpas they should be 2 i will fix that! Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your solution will be to group after the union

```
SELECT 
  geo_addresses
  ,count(*) as counter 
FROM (
   select origin_id as geo_addresses
   from rider_geo_addresses
   where rider_profile_id
   union all
   select destination_id as geo_addresses
   from rider_geo_addresses
   where rider_profile_id
) t
GROUP BY geo_addresses
ORDER BY counter desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved it! So i should have used an subquery and only one common counter !

Answer (score 0):

Using Union All instead of Union should give you the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` instead of `union all`:

```
select geo_addresses, ( coalesce(o.cnt, 0) + coalesce(d.cnt, 0) ) as counter
from (select origin_id as geo_addresses, count(*) as cnt
      from rider_geo_addresses
      where rider_profile_id
      group by origin_id
     ) o full join
     (select destination_id) as geo_addresses, count(*) as cnt
      from rider_geo_addresses
      where rider_profile_id
      group by  destination_id
     ) d
     using geo_addresses
order by counter desc;
```

Comment: Would i see any difference in performance by doing that?

Comment: @MarkosTzetzis . . . You would need to try it out.

Comment: Is there a way to measure performance ? Something like counting before and also after the query? Sorry for the many questions but  i am a beginner at this :)

Comment: @MarkosTzetzis . . . You can look at the explain plan or just measure the amount of time each query takes.